# Changing let value according to if result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please help me with this? I am trying to return a let variable depending on this if conditional below.

```
class Main extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let content = '';
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          // User is signed in.
          content = 'Logged in';
          // ...
        } else {
          content = 'Logged Out';
          // ...
        }
        console.log({content});
      });
    return <h1>{content}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Although it doesn't return anything.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: That auth function will be asynchronous so you can't return a value like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) for network engaging operation in react component.

Your code should be like  this:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { content: '' };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      this.setState({ content: user ? 'Logged in' : 'Logged Out' });
    })
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>{content}</h1>;
  }
}
```